# Update/Delete JSON array value in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, crud

I have a json array in my table. It contains an array. I can `create`, `append` or make my array `NULL`. Inside my stored procedure but I don't see any way to `pop` value from array. Apparently `JSON_Modify` may have solution as you can update `key` as well as **Single** `value` but how can I use it to modify my array?

```
--My Array 
Declare @json = '{"array":[123,456]}'
```

Desired results after update:

```
'{"array":[123]}'
```

Please note that `array` contain `int` values. Which are my `sub department id`. All values are (supposed to be) unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"array":[123,456]}';

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, MAX([key]) OVER() AS m_key
  FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.array') s
)
SELECT JSON_QUERY('[' + IIF(MAX(m_key) = 0, '', STRING_AGG(value,',') 
                   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [key])) + ']','$') AS array
FROM cte
WHERE [key] != m_key OR m_key = 0
FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Output:

```
{"array":[123]}
```

**[DBFiddle Demo SQL Server 2017](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=adb59119414e3376a43b7820576e13d6)**

Comment: Work like a charm, though in hurry I completed my work using `XML Path` which is weird using XML with JSON.

Comment: @abdulqayyum Great to hear that you solved your question anyway :)

Comment: I have added my solution just for comparison.

Comment: @lad2025 which is minimum version of SQL Server that supports OPENJSON ?

Comment: @abdulqayyum I modified my answer slightly to handle one element array. JSON is supported from SQL Server 2016

Comment: I have SQL Server 2017 on Linux but get an error for OPENJSON: 

Error: Invalid object name 'OPENJSON'.
SQLState:  S0002
ErrorCode: 208

Answer (score 1):

As I was in hurry I solved my problem following way, but I would really recommend not to use it. Please see answer above by @lad2025.

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX)
                          =(SELECT jsonDept 
                            FROM tblEmployee 
                            WHERE tblEmployeeID = @empid)
    DECLARE @newjson VARCHAR(MAX)= (
    SELECT LEFT(subdept, LEN(subdept)-1)
    FROM (
    SELECT Distinct value + ', ' FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.array') Where value <> @subdeptid
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) t (subdept))
    UPDATE tblEmployee SET jsonDept = '{"array":['+ @newjson +']}' WHERE tblEmployeeID = @empid
```